# assertthat in R with pairlist

Tags: r, assert, assertthat

I am trying to use `assertthat::assert_that()` on several conditions to be tested, which are collected in a `pairlist'.

The `pairlist` that I have a looks like this:

```
pairlist_1 <- as.pairlist(alist(is.null(list()), is.na(list())))

print(pairlist_1)

[[1]]

is.null(list())

[[2]]

is.na(list())
```

Now, I check the type of the `pairlist` and its elements:

```
print(typeof(pairlist_1))
[1] "pairlist"

print(typeof(pairlist_1[[1]]))
[1] "language"

print(typeof(pairlist_1[[2]]))
[1] "language"
```

I try to use `assert_that` and check it is working:

```
assertthat::assert_that(2 + 2 == 4)
[1] TRUE

assertthat::assert_that(is.null(list()))
Error: list() is not NULL
```

**PROBLEM**

However, when I try to use `assert_that` on the `pairlist` element directly, I get ...

```
assertthat::assert_that(pairlist_1[[1]])
Error: assert_that: assertion must return a logical value
```

... instead of `Error: list() is not NULL` as above, meaning that the assert_that() function cannot be executed.

I tried to `eval`uate the expressions in the pairlist and then assert the return value, but if I do `assertthat::assert_that(eval(pairlist_1[[1]]))` I get `Error: eval(expr = pairlist_1[[1]]) is not TRUE`. I want to get the same error that I get with `assertthat::assert_that(is.null(list())), which is: Error: list() is not NULL` .

How can I apply testthat::test_that() *directly* on my `pairlist` elements? Alternatively, how can I *extract* the `pairlist` elements and successfully apply testthat::test_that() on them?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what conditions you want to test. Your attempts don't make any sense and I can't infer your intentions from them.

Comment: I want to test the conditions included in the pairlist.
I want to be able to apply assert_thatI() on conditions that are elements of a pairlist.

I would like to run assertthat::assert_that(pairlist_1[[1]]) and get an assertthat error message.

Making sense now?

Comment: Does that mean you want to `eval`uate the expressions in the pairlist? And then assert the return value?

Comment: I tried that, but if I do `assertthat::assert_that(eval(pairlist_1[[1]]))` I get `Error: eval(expr = pairlist_1[[1]]) is not TRUE`. I want to get the same error that I get with `assertthat::assert_that(is.null(list()))`, which is: `Error: list() is not NULL` .

Comment: I have added this explanation in the text of the question above as it might be helpful.

Comment: Just a note: pairlists are deprecated https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Pairlist-objects

Answer (score 1):

Just compute on the language:

```
eval(substitute(assertthat::assert_that(x), 
                list(x = pairlist_1[[1]])))
#Error: list() is not NULL
```